# CSS3 linear gradient banding

Tags: javascript, css, linear-gradients

I have tried creating gradient color changing banner like the one on this 
[site](https://www.pixelapse.com/explore) but have seemed to run into serious issues with color banding. Can anyone tell me if the color changing effect on this site is possible without using the canvas element?

Sorry I'm new to this.

Any feedback is appreciated.

This fiddle must be run in Firefox. Sorry for that.

```
#solid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 380px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, rgb(105, 80, 102), #2E8ECE);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, rgb(105, 80, 102), #2E8ECE);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(105, 80, 102), #2E8ECE);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t66bgLwj/1/)

Comment: Can you show us your code, and maybe have a link to a http://jsfiddle.net example

Comment: What is the color changing effect that you are talking about? I only see a gradient and it is definitely possible to create that without using Canvas. That gradient seems fairly straight forward to me. You can get the code by inspecting that site itself. It is `background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1a2980 10%,#26d0ce 90%);`.

Comment: Hi Harry, if you watch the header background you will see the color changing, it's on a cycle though and there is maybe a 15/20 period where it does not change.

Comment: @AndrewBone Hi Andrew. I've included a speeded up simple example. Thank you.

Comment: @Devstack I did not see your fiddle before posting the answer but it seems like your fiddle already does something similar. Did you have any specific problems that you were trying to address? If yes, please indicate that and I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `linear-gradient` background image and JavaScript like in the below snippet. All that is required is to constantly keep changing the `rgb()` color values of the gradient by using the JS `setInterval` method.

**Note:** The coding is done such that after the `rgb()` values reach a certain threshold they go back to their original state immediately. You can also modify the code such that it increments till a certain level is reached and then decrements so that it kind of oscillates between a high and a low threshold.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.gradient-div');

/* Set the initial rgb() color values for the start and end colors */
var startColorRed = 62,
  startColorGreen = 79,
  startColorBlue = 216,
  endColorRed = 251,
  endColorGreen = 38,
  endColorBlue = 103;

/* set the original gradient as the element's background image */

el.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(' + startColorRed + ', ' + startColorGreen + ', ' + startColorBlue + ') 10% , rgb(' + endColorRed + ', ' + endColorGreen + ', ' + endColorBlue + ') 90%)';

/* function to change the gradient's colors */
function changeGrad() {
  /* do whatever math operation that is required on the rgb values of the color */
  if (endColorRed >= 151) endColorRed--;
  else endColorRed = 251;
  if (startColorBlue >= 116) startColorBlue--;
  else startColorBlue = 216;
  if (endColorBlue <= 203) endColorBlue++;
  else endColorBlue = 103;
  if (startColorGreen <= 179) startColorGreen++;
  else startColorGreen = 79;
  if (endColorGreen <= 138) endColorGreen++;
  else endColorGreen = 38;
  el.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(' + startColorRed + ', ' + startColorGreen + ', ' + startColorBlue + ') 10% , rgb(' + endColorRed + ', ' + endColorGreen + ', ' + endColorBlue + ') 90%)';
}

/* Call the changeGrad function at regular intervals to change the gradient's colors */
window.setInterval(changeGrad, 500);
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='gradient-div'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, great answer. The issue that I was having with the color banding appears to have been a speed issue. Never the less, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Devstack: You're welcome. Glad that the answer helped you :)